# How do I solve Flurry iOS SDK issue with Deprecated API usage of UIWebView?

Tags: ios, xcode, flurry, flurry-analytics

We have an iOS app that uses Flurry as an analytics capture tool, which is integrated using the pods `Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurrySDK`, I am getting emails from apple saying "Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs", I am not using any UIWewbView in my app, please suggest a solution for this.

Comment: Does the Flurry framework use it?

Comment: Either check if their is update to Flurry pod which uses WKWebView instead of UIWebView, or contact Flurry to use WKWebView if no update found. Once Flurry provides updated pod, use it & you won't receive such mails from Apple

Answer (score 0):

The Analytics SDK has a mention of UIWebView in the comments, but does not actively call the API. The comment will be removed in an upcoming release.